# How to show/hide single div only with jquery .slidetoggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show/display a single one div only when user click with jquery

For example when user click the "**Promo**" the promo content will show,

and when user click "**Sports**" the sports content will display and the promo content will hide... so on

I have this working code but when I click it shows all the content at once.

**HTML**

```
<div class="clickto_showme">Promo</div>
<div class="showcontent">
  <p> Content for promo </p>
</div>

<div class="clickto_showme">Sports</div>
<div class="showcontent">
  <p> Content for Sports </p> 
</div>


<div class="clickto_showme">News</div>
<div class="showcontent">
  <p> Content for News </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.showcontent {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
  $('.clickto_showme').click(function() {
        $('.showcontent').slideToggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
```

A working JSFIDDLE is here http://jsfiddle.net/jowa513p/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to manipulate the required element relative to the current element clicked; and **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** to get the sibling.

```
$('.clickto_showme').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.showcontent').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jowa513p/3/)

Comment: nice. its perfect @ShaunakD

Comment: Use `$(this).closest('.promotion_item_container').next('.show_promotion').slideToggle('slow');` as the promotion element is not the direct sibling/next element. http://jsfiddle.net/9yafbbh8/1/ Also `#details_pane` ID occurs multiple time s and duplicate IDs are invalid. Use class=details_pane

Comment: you are right because of ID "#details_pane" causing trouble.